# Removing duplicates and not valid entries from a select box, but not refreshing the whole box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write a web form, which will have selectable options based on users input from earlier in the form.

Where I'm getting stuck is;

- I have a table room types, which is just td tags with input tags (type=text).  These are filled in by a user, so I've no idea what they are..
- I've got a button to add extra lines to this table (Jquery to add another td tag and input tag)
- Users add as many lines as needed

The next part of the form is to fill in Rooms, and select the type for each room.  The table layout is the same (except there are two columns, rather than one), and extra lines are added via another button with Jquery.

What I'd like to be able to do, is for new lines added to have two columns in the table.  One input text field, and the other a select box with options taken from the table above.

I've managed to get this working to a point.  But as users may go back to edit options from the original (room types) table, I need the select boxes to adjust their values based on what the original table currently says.

I can get this working by emptying and re-populating my select boxes everytime one of the input fields accessed (using OnBlur, which is probably not the most effective way to do this), but since it removes entries from the bxes, and then re-populates, any of the select boxes that have been populated already get reset.  I only want invalid options (i.e. values that do not exist in the original table) to be reset.

I've been looking/playing at this for a long time now, but my programming abilities are only what I've taught from here and google, whilst messing around on a few very small things before...

My HTML code as it stands (well, part of my code, I've removed all the irrelevant code to keep it simple) is here:

```
<div id="rm_types_info">
    <table id="room_types_table">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="room_types" onblur="edit_rooms_select();" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <button type="button" onclick="rmtypes('room_types_table');">Add Another Room Type</button>
</div>

<div id="rooms_info">
    <table id="rooms_table">
        <tr>
            <th>Room Number</th>
            <th>Room Type</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td>
                <select class="room_type_select">
                    <option value="Please Choose">Please Choose</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <button type="button" onclick="rooms('rooms_table');">Add Another Room</button>
</div>
```

and my JQuery is;

```
<script>
    var userscounter=2
    var rmtypescounter=1
    var roomscounter=2

    function users(ID){
        document.getElementById(ID).insertRow(userscounter).innerHTML = '<td><input type="text" /></td><td><input type="text" /></td>';
        userscounter++;
    };

    function rmtypes(ID){
        document.getElementById(ID).insertRow(rmtypescounter).innerHTML = '<td><input type="text" class="room_types" onblur="edit_rooms_select();" /></td>';
        rmtypescounter++;
    }

    function rooms(ID){
        document.getElementById(ID).insertRow(roomscounter).innerHTML = '<td><input type="text" /></td><select class="room_type_select"><option value="Please Choose">Please Choose</option></select></td>';
        roomscounter++;
    };


    function edit_rooms_select(){   
        var roomtypelist = $('.room_type_select');
        roomtypelist.empty()
        $('#room_types_table tr td input').each(function(){
            var text = $(this).val();
            roomtypelist.append('<option value='+text+'>'+text+'</option>');
        });
    }
</script>
```

I've removed the Jquery that was removing the duplicates, since it was definately not working how it needs to...

I'm aware that I may be going about this completely the wrong way, and if using td tags or inputs etc is completely wrong, I'm happy to change the whole form it necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure this isn't the most effective way to do what I need, but this is how I managed to get it to work...

My HTML...

```
<div id="rm_types_info">
    <table id="room_types_table">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="2" class="room_types" onblur="edit_rooms_select();" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <button type="button" onclick="rmtypes('room_types_table');">Add Another Room Type</button>
</div>

<div id="rooms_info">
    <table id="rooms_table">
        <tr>
            <th>Room Number</th>
            <th>Room Type</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td>
                <select class="room_type_select" id="room_type_select1" >
                    <option value="1">Please Choose</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <button type="button" onclick="rooms('rooms_table');edit_rooms_select();">Add Another Room</button>
</div>
```

And the JQuery scripts relevant.  In particular, it was the final function "edit_rooms_select()", and specifically the "Add new options to each select" that I was struggling with.

```
<script>
    var rmtypescount=3;
    var room_type_select_count=2;

    function rmtypes(){
        $('#room_types_table tr:last').after('<tr><td><input type="text" name='+rmtypescount+' class="room_types" onblur="edit_rooms_select();" /></td></tr>');
        rmtypescount++;
    };

    function rooms(){
        $('#rooms_table tr:last').after('<tr><td><input type="text" /></td><td><select id="room_type_select'+room_type_select_count+'" class="room_type_select"><option value="1">Please Choose</option></select></td></tr>');
        room_type_select_count++
    };

    function edit_rooms_select(){       
        $('#room_types_table tr td input').each(function(){
            var name = $(this).attr('name');
            var value = $(this).val();
//Add New Options to each select            
            $('#rooms_table select').each(function(){
                var last = $(this).children('option:last').val();
                if (name > last) {
                    $(this).append('<option value="'+name+'">'+value+'</option>');
                };
            });
//Change any room types that have been edited           
            $('.room_type_select option').each(function(){
                var match = $(this).val();
                if(name == match){
                    $(this).text(value)
                };
            });
//Remove Blank Entries
            if(value == ''){
                $('.room_type_select option[value='+name+']').remove();
            };
        });
    };
</script>
```

I think that the edit_rooms_select function is much more expensive than it needs to be.  For what I require, this isn't going to be a problem, but I would be very interested to see how other people suggest the lists are edited, following my requirements..
 - All user inputs from the room_types_table must be options in the select boxes in the rooms_table
 - Any input changed in the room_types_table must have its relevant option in the select boxes changed to match
 - Any input that is left blank (or later deleted) from the room_types_table must be removed from the select boxes
 - Any select box that has a selection which is then removed from the room_types_table must be reset back to its original "Please Choose" option.

If anyone can suggest better ways to do this, or can tidy my code in any way, I'd like to see the code, and also have it explained, as I'm very inexperienced with Javascript/Jquery.